# How does the program control flow in generator?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand the flow of control while defining a generator.

```py
def countdown(num)
    print('Starting')
    while num > 0:
        yield num
          num -= 1
val = countdown(5)
```

when I call `next(val)`, `Starting` gets printed followed by the number 5
but in the subsequent calls only the number gets printed. why am I not seeing `Starting`? and why does it show an error when I call `next(val)` more than 5 times? Any help in understanding the control flow will be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a help forum or discussion forum. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. When a generator is *finished* it raises a `StopIteration` Exception - pretty sure that is in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `next()` the first time, execution begins at the start of the function body and continues until the next yield statement where the value to the right of the statement is returned.

Subsequent calls to `next()` continue from the yield statement to the end of the function, and loop around and continue from the start of the while loop until another `yield` is called.

If yield is not called (which in your case means that you don’t go into the while function because `num <= 0`) a StopIteration exception will be raised.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Hope its correct now

Comment: Just about, yeah! `while` is a statement, not a function, and you're referring to the `while` block, i.e. the indented block that follows the `while` statment.

Answer (score 1):

Move `Starting` inside the while block:

```
def countdown(num):
    while num > 0:
        print('Starting')
        num -= 1
        yield num

val = countdown(5)
for i in range(5):
    print(next(val))
```

Output:

```
Starting
4
Starting
3
Starting
2
Starting
1
Starting
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, currently you're simply only printing `Starting` once, and since it isn't `yield`ed, it comes with the first `yield`. Why shouldn't it throw an error after it reaches `0`? it should, since the `yield` repentance will stop, and `next` only works if there are still gonna be more `yield`. To tweak it a little so that it doesn't print `Starting` with only `5`, but as well as the other numbers, and doesn't raise any errors, do:

```
def countdown(num):
    while num > 0:
        print('Starting')
        yield num
        num -= 1
    while True:
        yield 'The number reached zero, it stopped'
val = countdown(5)
```

Testing with:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(next(val))
```

Gives:

```
Starting
5
Starting
4
Starting
3
Starting
2
Starting
1
The number reached zero, it stopped
The number reached zero, it stopped
The number reached zero, it stopped
The number reached zero, it stopped
The number reached zero, it stopped
```